# Gathering information from active browser tabs

Tags: google-chrome, cookies, browser, tabs, mozilla

Let's assume that we have 2 tabs open (my website and the second).

I would like to know if there is any chance for my website to gather information like f.ex: link of the "second" website, while Im there (while it's active)?

Comment: From the context of a normal website? Of course not, otherwise all the world would know by now what pr0n sites you visit …

Comment: what do you mean by "normal website"? is there another solution to do this?

Comment: By normal website I mean just any website the user might surf to; as opposed to a browser extension, which has more permissions to access what content is currently displayed in the browser’s different tabs.